# Transición en función javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Se puede añadir transiciones en las funciones javascript como las transitions de CSS?

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class1');
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class2');
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class3');
});
```

```css
body {align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;}

body.class1 {
background-color: red;
}

body.class2 {
background-color: green;
}

body.class3 {
background-color:powderblue;
}

button {padding: 15px 32px;
  margin: 10px;
font-size: 16px;
border-radius: 12px;
border: 2px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="class1">
<button id="btn1">RED</button>
<button id="btn2">GREEN</button>
<button id="btn3">BLUE</button>
</body>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con añadir transiciones a las funciones de JavaScript? No termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres con la pregunta. Te recomiendo que leas [ask].

Comment: Una vez yo respondí [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160753/css-cambio-de-colores-por-intervalos-de-tiempo) similar. Quizás te sirva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo respuesta, para añadir un fade a un cambio de clases hecho desde un script:
1 - Usar Jquery y jquery-ui
2 - Agregar al cambio de clase la velocidad de animación, easeOutBounce

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class1',1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class2',1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass(); 
 $('body').addClass('class3',1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});
```

```css
body {align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
}

body.class1 {
background-color: red;
}

body.class2 {
background-color: green;
}

body.class3 {
background-color:powderblue;
}

button {padding: 15px 32px;
margin: 80px 10px;
font-size: 16px;
border-radius: 12px;
border: 2px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body class="class1">
<button id="btn1">RED</button>
<button id="btn2">GREEN</button>
<button id="btn3">BLUE</button>
</body>
```

No funciona con background-images:

[Ejemplo en Codepen](https://codepen.io/danielillo/pen/VrampV)

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o una edición a la pregunta? Parece más lo segundo que lo primero. Si estás intentando responder a tu propia pregunta, te recomiendo que traigas las ideas generales de la respuesta en inglés a tu respuesta en español, y que incluyas el código en tu publicación en lugar de en un sitio externo como Codepen. (Lee [answer] para más información)

Comment: Es respuesta, está en el primer enlace (no el del Codepen)

Comment: OK. Es que tal como está redactada no parece una respuesta y fue marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Para que sea de más ayuda a otros usuarios que puedan tener el mismo problema, sería bueno que la editaras añadiendo las partes claves de los enlaces a tu pregunta. Los enlaces se rompen y entonces tu respuesta dejaría de tener sentido.